# Removing and adding classes inside an ng-class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, jquery-selectors

Having some elements which contain an ng-class which works like a ternary operator:

`ng-class="$ctrl.something ? 'fa-minus' : 'fa-plus'"`

In order to access them, for example, all the elements having `fa-minus` can be stored into a list:

```
const elementList = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-minus');
```

My question is if it's possible to modify inside the ng-class. For example, for all the elements having `fa-minus` to change it to `fa-square`.

I tried several methods like removing and adding a class after that:

```
    const elementList = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-minus');
    document.forEach(document=> document.classList.remove('.fa-minus'));
    document.forEach(document=> document.classList.add('fa-square'));
```

It doesn't work, probably because the original one is an ng-class and not a classic css class.

**It shoudn't change the original ng-class. I want to change it only inside a function which creates an export file**

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Avoid direct DOM manipulation when using AngularJS. You could do that in angular way using below code.

**HTML**

```
ng-class="$ctrl.getClass()"
```

**Controller**

```
var $ctrl = this;
var MINUS = 'fa-minus';
var PLUS = 'fa-plus';

getClass () {
   return $ctrl.something ? MINUS : PLUS
}

changeMinusClass(newClass) {
   MINUS = newClass
}

onClickOfSomething () {
   this.changeMinusClass('fa-square')
}
```

Comment: it shoudn't change the original ng-class. I want to change it only inside a function which creates an export file

Comment: @LeoMessi oh man. Please mention such important things in the question at initial level. Please update your question

Answer (score 1):

You can `remove()` the class just before `add()`. You should not use `document` as name of your variable. Also it is not good practice to use same name as the parameter of the handler function.

The following example shows how this could be done:

```js
var d = document.querySelectorAll('span');
d.forEach(el=> {
  el.classList.remove('fa-minus');
  el.classList.add('fa-square');
});

// for demonstration
document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(s => console.log(s.getAttribute('class')));
```

```html
<span class="fa-minus">Test 1</span>
<span class="fa-minus">Test 2</span>
```

Comment: @LeoMessi, please do not use the two functions in the same line. Use individual statement like my updated answer.....

Comment: @LeoMessi, I am little bit surprised. I wish I could see that live!